# Swagger codegen compilation issues due to field starting with an underscore

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I have the following `openApi` definition, notice the `type` and `_type` fields:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: 'title'
  description: 'description'
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /pet:
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          description: successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
components:
  schemas:
    Pet:
      type: object
      properties:
        type:
          type: string
        _type:
          type: string
```

When I try and generate a Java client using the above, I get the following results in `io.swagger.client.model.Pet`

```java
public class Pet {
...
   /**
   * Get type
   * @return type
  **/
  @Schema(description = "")
  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public Pet _type(String _type) {
    this._type = _type;
    return this;
  }

   /**
   * Get _type
   * @return _type
  **/
  @Schema(description = "")
  public String getType() {
    return _type;
  }

  public void setType(String _type) {
    this._type = _type;
  }
...
}
```

Which will not compile since the methods `getType` and `setType` are duplicated. How can I update my `openApi` to avoid this?

I don't care what getter/setter methods are used, however I am not able to change the field names.

This can be reproduced using https://editor.swagger.io/.

Update: I've simplified my question substantial from what I original posted which included the java classes the `openApi` definition l was generated from.

Comment: Are you using the online client or another library, https://editor.swagger.io/ generates them correctly?

Comment: I"m using the maven package `io.swagger.core.v3::swagger-jaxrs2::2.1.4` to generate my `openApi.json` file, and then `io.swagger.codegen.v3::swagger-codegen-maven-plugin::3.0.22` to for the `codegen`

Comment: @Aman I've updated my question so easy to reproduce in editor.swagger.io. Thanks for pointing that out. it's a fantastic resource.

Comment: I suppose the problem is not of `swagger-codegen`, rather of `jackson`. I had the same problem with spring long time ago. I don't know how to apply it for this scenario. check it here https://dzone.com/articles/jackson-property-custom-naming-strategy

Comment: The problem is with `swagger-codegen`, since it can't handle cases two unique properties if one starts with a `_`. I've updated my question to remove the Jackson annotations since the above could happen with any `openApi`. If I could change the name  used in `@JsonProperty("_type")` I could avoid the problem. But since the API in question is in use, changing the properties names is not an option.

Comment: I think you miss understood my point. let me put it as answer since the text is longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem comes when **resolving** property names (which is done by `PropertyNamingStrategy`). So, usually the first `_` might be skipped. As in for example `PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE` which uses:

```
private static String toSnakeCase(String input) {
            if (input == null) return input;
            int length = input.length();
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(length * 2);
            int resultLength = 0;
            boolean wasPrevTranslated = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                char c = input.charAt(i);
                if (i > 0 || c != '_') // skip first starting underscore
                {
                    if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                        if (!wasPrevTranslated && resultLength > 0 && result.charAt(resultLength - 1) != '_') {
                            result.append('_');
                            resultLength++;
                        }
                        c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
                        wasPrevTranslated = true;
                    } else {
                        wasPrevTranslated = false;
                    }
                    result.append(c);
                    resultLength++;
                }
            }
            return resultLength > 0 ? result.toString() : input;
        }
```

This [link](https://gist.github.com/silas/3b41e6ed4031c11f919767a74829ffea#file-snakecaseconverter-java-L54) might give you a clue on how property name resolution works.

Comment: That's super helpful! I'll try implementing my own `ModelConverter`.

Comment: I am glad I helped.